# vim-latex view document in different folder

Tags: vim, latex, vim-plugin

I have installed vim-latex. It all works perfectly, but it creates a lot of auxiliary files. I use texlive, which has the option `-output-directory=DIR` to separate temp files, but the .pdf is put in this DIR too. And, when I use `\lv` to view the pdf, vim-latex doesn't find the pdf file.

How can I configure \lv in vim-latex to view a pdf in a different folder from the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same setup. My simple solution is a symbolic link to the pdf file in DIR.

On Linux:

```
ln -s DIR/project.pdf project.pdf
```

On Windows:

```
mklink project.pdf DIR/project.pdf
```

Comment: I have worked in windows, I tried your solution creating a direct acces, but \lv don't show the pdf.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I use zumatra, but the inversesearch don't work with the link. The inverseSearch work perfectly with the origial pdf.

Sorry in linux (unix) is the same?

Comment: I think that the use of -output-directory is not good, the references (bibtex) didn't work, the inverse search, didn't work, etc...

Thanks for your answers!